# what is NSIndexPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c

What exactly is the job of NSIndexPath, 
What I understand is, IndexPath variable is used to refer the cell which we want to display ?:o ?
But what value does it store ? I mean., 
What is the internal process that happen to setup an indexPath variable

Comment: It seems like you're asking three different questions.

Comment: Im confused about IndexPath,Any info would help !

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It is used as a vector for referencing arrays within arrays. For example you can represent a path to array[a][b][c] using an IndexPath. Internally it is used for iPhone list views, for example a list view that allows you to select a country, then gives you an option of regions, followed by a list of cities in the said region. The indexpath to the city you selected would include the path to it through the country and region.

Specifically for UITableViews, NSIndexPath plays a slightly more expanded role. UIKit adds the row and section properties to an instance of NSIndexPath, and a class method + indexPathForRow:inSection:.

Therefore if you want to select or delete a specific row in a table, you would need to pass an instance of NSIndexPath to that table. To create that, you would use indexPathForRow:inSection to create an NSIndexPath instance.

If you have an existing NSIndexPath that you want to get info about and it's from a table view, then use its row and section properties to get the data.

If you encounter index paths outside of the table view, be careful regarding the specifics of its use. Either way, in general, it is a reference to a specific element in arrays of arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the reply !! 
That was what I was looking out for

Answer (score 15):

In iOS the `NSIndexPath` objects are always of length 2. They're used for example to index a table view cell. The first index in a `NSIndexPath` object is called the *section*, the second is the *row*. An index path object with section 0 and row 0 indicates the first row in the first section. 
Thats all you need to know when dealing with index paths on iOS.

Comment: Refering to the link : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html

..
>>
They mention Index path as  1.4.3.2 , so according to your explanation, Are we selecting the sub-sections? Like section 1, subsection4, subsection 3 and then row 2 ?

Comment: I assume that I got a downvote on my answer based on this one. Unless I'm mistaken, this is not true. The section and row applies to many cases, especially when you are breaking a table view into multiple sections. However the actual fact is still true that they represent a path to a specific node - if it's just a section (first node) and index (second node). Also, the Apple documentation is very explicit here, including page 8 of this iOS specific document: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/NSIndexPath_Class.pdf

Comment: To expand a bit more on it. UIKit adds the row and section properties to an instance of NSIndexPath, and a class method `+ indexPathForRow:inSection:`. So if you stick with those two properties and this initializer, the details of what the rest of NSIndexPath does shouldn't be too important. Sorry for all the confusing detail!

Comment: Oh !! Thanks a lot for taking your time off, and am glad u mentioned about the method +indexPathForRow:inSection:  ..
I was kind of confused about indexPath concept, This would do !! Thanks !
One last Query : Basically, how will the value be stored in indexPath object.., like a NSString "1.4.5.3" or is there any other way of doing it (just for curiousness), You say that UIKit adds the row and section properties to instance of NSIndexPath., will that be an integer value ... [confused again !! ] sorry for not compling the comment properly :P

Comment: Not a problem at all, glad I could help! As for how it's stored, definitely not as a string. The documentation implies it's a C array of NSUInteger values (not an NSArray, just a dynamic NSUInteger *). It doesn't matter though, as it isn't safe to assume anything about how it is stored, as it might change between versions. You just pass values into it as a black box, and then get those same values out (and it takes care of the rest).

Answer (score 7):

Apple's class reference documentation is useful only for people who HAVE the mental model instantiated into their cognitive processes. When someone asks a question such as the original post, even if they are unable to fully articulate their confusion, the class reference documentation is some of the most wonderful non-information ever published. I too am struggling to figure out how---in the words of another SO answer---to fill in "// compute some index path" (knowing only an integer offset of the cell... I want to select my nth item), and am looking for the same level of conceptual overview as the original post, so I thought I'd explain the dilemma a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but there is more information [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: All I want to know is why do we use IndexPath in UITableView